# Odeint function by scipy.integrate does not follow the given time vector when solving the system

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am trying to solve a ODE matrix system in which one of the terms change with time. To change it to the accurate value, the code should search within the predefined time vector to find at what instant it is, and use the same index (named *control* on the code) to set the values in the matrix, as shown below:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint as ode

#(Here, I cut some of the non-relevant to the issue objects, that I can guarantee that are correct)

def susp(x,TT): 
    dxdt=[]
    control=0
    dxdtlong=np.zeros((1,4),float)

    for i in range(time_size):
        ttt=t[i]      
        if TT!=ttt:
            control+=1
        else:
            break

    W[0,0]=zr[control]
    W[1,0]=zrp[control]

    matriz1=np.matrix(np.dot(A,x))
    matriz2=np.matrix(np.dot(H,W))

    for j in range(len(matriz1)):
        for k in range(len(matriz1[0])):
            dxdtlong=matriz1[k][j]+matriz2[k][j]  

    dxdt.append(dxdtlong[0,0])
    dxdt.append(dxdtlong[0,1])
    dxdt.append(dxdtlong[0,2])
    dxdt.append(dxdtlong[0,3])

    data=np.reshape(dxdt,np.size(dxdt))
    return data

x=ode(susp, x0_reshaped, t, full_output=1)
```

t is a equally spaced time vector, created with *linspace*.

Oddly, when running this code, the second time point called by ODE isn't t[1], but a value that isn't even in my time vector.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try replacing `if TT!=ttt` with `if TT<t[i]`. In general, the described task is called "interpolation", you will find in scipy.interpolate functions that do this in several ways, your behavior is a zero-order hold.

Comment: Can you provide a [example]?

Comment: How do you determine the ODE time step? You know the difference between the internal time steps of the method that are adapted to the "curvature" of the ODE and the requested output times where the values get interpolated from the internal data?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I've tried the replacement, and it actually worked! Thank you for your answer! At first I was kinda doubting it, but with this other answer on another question ( [scipy.integrate.odeint` automatically adjusts time steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247021/scipy-integrate-odeint-automatically-adjusts-time-steps) ) I understood the reason behind it!